# Shopping cart remove button is not removing the products on ubercart

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am using [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) module and on my cart page "remove" button is not removing the products from the cart. It is displaying the message "Please check your quantity and try again".Please help!!